# Kendo Grid- Apply CSS style for only numeric columns

Tags: kendo-ui

I have many grids in my application. some of the columns are numeric ones.
I want to apply a specific css style (direction: ltr) for all numeric columns without specifying is for each one. Is their a way to apply the style on all numeric columns?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Kendo grid has a [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) event that will be fired once the grid has finished rendering the cells.  From this event, you'll be able to loop into the grid's `view` and `column` and set each cell css individually.

Note that the type is part of the [model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model), not the column itself.

```
$.each(kendoGrid.columns, function (index, column) {

    //Get the type from the model
    var type = kendoGrid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields[column.field].type;

    var jqTd;

    //Extra logic to handle locked columns
    //nth-child is 1-base
    if (columnScan.locked) {
        lockCount++;
        jqTd = kendoGrid.lockedContent.find("tbody>tr>td:nth-child({0})".formatWith(index + 1));
    } else {
        jqTd = kendoGrid.tbody.find(">tr>td:nth-child({0})".formatWith(index + 1 - lockCount));
    }

    if (type == "number") {
        jqTd.css("background-color", "red");
    }

});
```